# Beyond Compare - ignore white lines

Tags: diff, beyondcompare

I'm using Beyond compare to Diff HTML/PHP files between a windows PC and a Linux box. I want to compare file contents.

I can't figure out how to get it to ignore white space (line spaces or space at the start/end of lines).

I'm sure this should be doable, right?

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue...  I can get it to ignore them when I open the two files, but as part of the initial bulk comparison it's still showing them as having differences.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your file format and turning on the Ignore Unimportant Differences option:

http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=4067

If that doesn't work for you you might want to take a look at WinMerge as a free alternative: http://winmerge.org/

Comment: Still can't get this to work. I want to compare everything EXCEPT white space between the last character of a line, and the next character that is NOT a white space.